# How to add button in UICollectionView for inserting new data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Good day! 
On the screen below you can see how the user could add new players. By touching the cell with "plus" new cell with the name of player (for ex. "Player 3") will be inserting. And cell with "plus" will shift down.
[image]
Will you advice how to do this? thx for answering:)

Comment: Are you using a tableView containing buttons, or just buttons? (If it was a tableView, you would just make sure the + button was added to the last cell, and increment the numberOfRowsInSection value by 1 to move it down).

Comment: No, am using collectionView...

Comment: Apologies, it was obvious from the title :-) In that case, I would suggest a similar approach. You basically make sure the + button is the last item in your collectionView each time and increment your number of items by 1 in the numberOfItemsInSection method.

Comment: @Gismay yes, it works)) checkout your comment as answer) i'll mark it as true)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You basically make sure the + button is the last item in your collectionView each time and increment your number of items by 1 in the numberOfItemsInSection method.

Comment: This will make it difficult to work with selection. Better use a footer section described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577984/add-button-at-the-end-of-collection-view-in-storyboard